# Uploading photo to facebook fan page using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey all, I'm trying to upload an image to a fan page album using the graph api but it keeps uploading it to my profile instead of the fan page album.

any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the Page access token, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens since you are operating as a page in this instance.